# Can I update a form question every day based on the date and a spreadsheet of information?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm not a very technical person when it comes to coding languages, but I'm trying to make a Google Form for my daily warm ups (I'm a teacher) that will update one text box with the date and the new question that corresponds to the date in a spreadsheet. My goal is to just add to the spreadsheet and the form will auto-populate the question for kids to answer.

Comment: Hi there, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Are you intending to use [Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/) for this or just a single Spreadhsheet ?

Comment: I'd like to use Forms. Basically have a spreadsheet with the dates and the questions and have the form update automatically each day with the corresponding question.

Comment: What do you mean by ```have the form update automatically every day```? Do you mean that every time an user submits a response this response will be recorded on the Spreadsheet?